# JavaScript: how to create an alert if an existing object is instantiated with a specific value?

Tags: javascript

(This is just for personal curiosity)

I would like to setup an automatic alert when-ever one of the built-in JavaScript objects (meaning: objects that I have not defined myself) is instantiated with a specific value.

So here is for example a **non**-built-in object called "Test":

```
function Test(first, last) {
   this.firstName = first;
   this.lastName = last;
}
```

One of the things I have tried with is adding a self-executing function named "checkName" to the "Test" object, like so:

```
Test.prototype.checkName = function() {
   var n = this.firstName;
   if (n == "Mickey") {
      alert("It's Mickey!!");
   }
}();
```

However instantiating this as follows does not result in an alert:

```
var a = new Test("Mickey", "Mouse");
```

Is it possible to augment existing objects so as to create an automatic alert when a property has some specific value?

If it is, how can this be done?

Comment: You'll have to call `this.checkName()` in the constructor itself; nothing's going to call it for you.

Comment: thanks @Pointy but is there a way to add such a call to the constructor of an object that I have not created myself?

Comment: You can't change functions that already exist.  What is the overall thing you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Pointy I thought that you can augment objects created from existing functions through the prototype object? Anyway I was actually just trying to figure out if this was possible, purely in order to learn more about JS.

Comment: You can do that, yes, but that's not the same thing as changing an existing function. It's fine to add methods to a prototype object, but nothing's going to find your new method and call them automatically.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can't read your mind. You must call the method manually.

And it must be a method, not an immediately invoked function expression. When you call it like that `this` becomes the global object in sloppy mode or unrefined in strict mode. So `this.firstName` will either be `window.firstName` or throw an exception.

```
function Test(first, last) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.checkName();
}
Test.prototype.checkName = function() {
  var n = this.firstName;
  if (n == "Mickey") {
    alert("It's Mickey!!");
  }
};
var a = new Test("Mickey", "Mouse");
```

Comment: thanks @Oriol but is there a way to add such a call to the constructor of an object that I have not created myself (such as one of the functions that come with JS)..?

Comment: @x457812 It depends, host objects can have non-standard behavior. Can you be more specific?

Comment: so lets say I would like to add a function to the JS alert() method so that when it's called with a specific text string, it pops up a second alert. Would this be possible?

Comment: Yes: `var _alert = window.alert; window.alert = function(str) { if(str == "foo"){ /* ... */} return _alert.apply(this, arguments); }`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lib `https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter` and extend Object.prototype to emit an event each time a object is created and make the event alert for you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify existing constructors, but you can replace them. The following code will alert on instantiations, and the replaced constructors will yield the same objects like before:

```
var _Set = Set;

Set = function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  alert(JSON.stringify(args));
  return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(_Set, [null].concat(args)));
};

new Set("kenyér"); // alerts ["kenyér"]
```

However you cannot expect any library to function properly after this, for example the `instanceof` operator no longer works:

```
new Set() instanceof Set  // will return false
new Set() instanceof _Set // will return true
```

Comment: this is interesting. Thanks @TamasHegedus. But you write that one "cannot expect any code run properly after this"...is the altered return values for the modified object the only consequence and if so, why would that stop any code from running properly? (I am probably reading too much to the word "any" here but please explain) Thanks!

Comment: @x457812 Sorry for not being clear here. Basically the thing is that we replace the constructor with a factory function, so the running environment is altered significantly. Libraries might depend on the `instanceof` operator, so they wont work.